# Using Zookeeper + Play + Cassandra DB (via Kundera)

Tags: cassandra, playframework-2.0, apache-zookeeper, kundera

Have anyone tried using Play framework(2.0.4) application with connect to cassandra db via kundera? I want to implement Zookeeper on top of cassandra DB. Have anyone tried combining them before?

Comment: Implementing the zookeeper api on top of cassandra will be very difficult, how do you plan on doing that?

Comment: what is your use-case exactly?  PlayOrm for cassandra has been considering usage and a plugin there, but it should rarely if ever be used for speed and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

I guess integration with play framework via Kundera is possible. Implementing zookeeper on top of cassandra is also possible, i guess. Did you look into cage API for this?

-Vivek